# Changing marker size in legends (gramm for Matlab)

Tags: matlab, plot, legend

I am using the [gramm toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/54465-gramm-complete-data-visualization-toolbox-ggplot2-r-like) to do plots of all sorts in Matlab. One thing I'm having to always edit post-hoc in most plots (i.e. using the Property Inspector) is the marker size in legends, which by default are tiny. This amounts to increasing lineWidth:

[image]

Gramm does have a function dedicated to changing marker sizes, set_point_options, but that only refers to markers in the main plot, and does not affect those in the legend. Similarly, the set_text_options function has scaling parameters for the title & text of the legend, but not for the markers.

Sadly, the toolbox's author is no longer available for support.

My usual way of changing legend marker sizes (for Matlab-native plot functions) is given below, but does not work with gramm plots:

```
x = 1:10;
plot(x, 1*x, 'o');
hold on;
plot(x, 2*x, 's');
[~, objh] = legend({'one','two'}); 
objhl = findobj(objh, 'type', 'line');
set(objhl, 'Markersize', 18);
% or, for Patch plots:
objhl = findobj(objh, 'type', 'patch'); 
set(objhl, 'Markersize', markerSize_legend);
```

Can anyone suggest a way to change lineWidth programatically, i.e. by adjusting some parameter of some gramm function?

Comment: Not sure what this toolbox of yours does, by default the markers in the legend match those of the plot, they have the same size. If you increase the size of the markers in the plot, those in the legend follow automatically.

Comment: I know. In this case, I want to control marker size separately.

Comment: I don’t think that is possible. You’d have to create two plots, one without a legend and a second one with a legend, and somehow hide the second plot in a way that only its legend is visible. Then adjusting the marker size of the second invisible plot would change the marker size of the legend.

Comment: That sounds like a hacky workaround, but but it might well be the only (easy) one. Any thoughts how to hide the second/dummy plot, but leave its legend visible AND bring it closer to the first plot?

Comment: You can manipulate the position of the legend independently of its axes. Maybe you can set the “visible” property of the axes, not sure if that also affects the legend. This would certainly be a trial and error thing to find out.